# How do I get access to the DBContext Templates for Code-First from Database Wizard?

Tags: visual-studio, entity-framework-4, t4

I'm doing Code First development with Visual Studio 2012. Since I'm in the early stages of the project I'm making a lot of schema and table changes and I've found that its a good step to periodically regenerate the table classes using the wizard in Visual Studio for 'Code First From Database' into a scratch project and copy over the generated code, since I will tend to miss adding a key field or collection or something when modifying the fields by hand.

Does Visual Studio use .tt files to do this, and if so how hard is it to set them up to use them outside of the wizard?

What I'm doing is working but using their templates would be nice.

thanks,

john

Comment: [code first](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx) doesn't use T4 templates. [emdx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/cc982042(v=vs.100).aspx) uses T4.

Comment: That is true, but the wizard that generates the initial skeleton appears to be using templates. That may not be the case, of course.